# Why are my <p> paragraphs appearing on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic website and I'm stylizing html with css. I put two paragraphs next to each other and they appear on the same line, although separately as two centered pieces.

For example:

`<p>ugh</p>`
`<p>yay</p>`

would show up in the website like

> ugh            yay

instead of

> ugh
>
> yay

The CSS I have for the paragraphs are:

```
p {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

NOTE TO EVERYONE: REMOVING INLINE-BLOCK DID NOT FIX IT

FULL CODE CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/sprot9uh/

Comment: you should use display:block; instead of display: inline-block;

Comment: you need to `width:100%` in class,

Comment: can you share your parent element style of p tag. @Jon

Comment: show the full code in a jsfiddle. There are other styles messing with it probably

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sprot9uh/ @StefanBob

Comment: @Jon with the HTML so the preview works too

Comment: @StefanBob That's why I'm frustrated as it's working there but not on vscode live server

Comment: better remove the question as it will get closed and you may get more downvotes, no one is able to see your issue and you already found it in a code we don't see

Answer (score 2):

```css
p {
  background: yellowgreen;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p class="inline">I'm an inline block element....
</p>

<p class="inline"> me too
</p>

<p> But I'm a block level element
</p>

<p>Me too
</p>
```

Comment: removing inline-block did not fix the issue sadly

Comment: FOUND SOULTION: the issue was that I had set flex-direction to row for some reason under sections

Comment: @Jon I noticed that in your css in the fiddle but was unsure since I did'nt see the whole code. Great, you solved it yourself

Answer (score 1):

remove `inline-block` for `p`

```
p {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Ok so I removed inline-block, and it didn't change anything

Comment: That's odd because it's still showing on same line for me

Comment: FOUND SOULTION: the issue was that I had set flex-direction to row for some reason under sections

Comment: `FOUND SOLUTION:` Cool

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `inline-block` does in your css. You can either completely remove it or just use `block`.

Comment: removing inline-block did not fix the issue sadly

Answer (score 0):

> add `display:block` in (p) tag instead of `display:inline-block;` and u can remove `display-inline-block` it's also worked...

Comment: removing inline-block did not fix the issue sadly

Comment: FOUND SOULTION: the issue was that I had set flex-direction to row for some reason under sections

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` elements are `display: block;` by default. Usually all you need is:

```
p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default display property of p tag is 'block' so you can remove the display property.

[You can refer the  jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/v30bL8u2/)

```
p {
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

Comment: FOUND SOULTION: the issue was that I had set flex-direction to row for some reason under sections

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your css code I think you have paragraphs `<P></P>` in `<section></section>` something like:

```
<section>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>456</p>
</section>
```

You have to change css for section (flex-direction from row to column):

```
section {
    background: white;
    color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```